# Export UV Seams

Tags: uv, export, seams

I'm trying to export this object from an old file in blender because the viewport is messed up.

When I export the object to FBX to a new Blender file The UV seams won't export it's just fresh mesh with no seams is there a way to bring the seams back the seams to the object?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you Append your mesh from the faulty blend file into your new one (File > Append... and select the correct object in the Mesh folder) the seams should be preserved. Alternatively, if it's just the viewport messed up, you can use File > Open in a new blend file, hit the 'N' key in the file selector, uncheck 'Load UI' and load your dud blend file preserving the standard layout.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpfull

Comment: Did it cure the problem for you? - I should have added that Blender's seams are native to blender and will never be kept if you export to any of the file formats such as fbx.

Comment: Yes it did, you are an angel sir.

Comment: Not sure about that, but thanks anyway! :^)